# What is the difference between creating Queue using Queue class of Spring and creating directly from RabbitMq Console?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We have to choose the best way of implementing RabbitMQ Queue.
We have two approaches 
1. Create a Queue and Bind using @Bean and Queue class in Spring.
2. Create a Queue in RabbitMQ web console itself.

We need to know which is the best way the Programming way or Console way and Why?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html for what can be done with queues. Depending on your scenario both approaches can be correct. You can let the consumer create a queue, bind it and consume from it. You can manually create and bind a queue using the admin tools. Or you can do both. What scenario do you have in mind? How would the resulting topology look? Why?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the better way is using the web console. Queue is an infrastructure and will be used by many applications. You should not provide full control of the infrastructure to applications. It should be maintained by the admin.

Also please consider the following aspects.

Security
Ease of use
Threats

Comment: This is not true. Depending on the scenario, it can be advisable for a consumer to create and bind a queue on the fly.